# Three Singles in Three Clubs

Tags: riddle, knowledge

These three belong to three different clubs.

> First one, very popular, is the singles-only club. It is closed for new
> membership.
>
> Second one, very useful, is for singles and couples. It is open for
> new members but it is very hard to get in now.
>
> Unlike the first two clubs, the third club is different for these three. The
> three singles are related to each other. Especially, two of them
> are talked about constantly and daily.
>
> Outside these clubs, when the three come together, you are looking at very popular food!

Who are they? What are the three clubs?

Hint

> They are not words

Comment: Since they are single, should they consider dating each other? But wait... someone's gonna be the third wheel...

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Until recently, the 2nd club used to provisionally allow trios, but then they made them drop their third wheels.

Comment: In the third club, I think only one of them is constantly talked about daily, unless you're a scientist. (The third one only if there happen to be some Americans around.)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The three singles are

> The letters c, f and k

The first club is

> The (latin) alphabet, which seems to have settled at 26 letters, and can be considered closed.

The second club is

> The periodic table, which consists of singles (H, C, O, etc) and pairs (Na, Mg etc). C is the symbol for carbon, F for Fluorine, K for Potassium. Each successive element contains one more proton in the nucleus, so it is currently only possible to join by having more than [118 protons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oganesson), but these elements are increasingly unstable.

The third club is

> Physical symbols for Temperature. C/F/K stand for Celsius, Fahrenheit and Kelvin, but only C and F are used daily for discussing the weather

Putting them together gives the popular food

> KFC

Comment: Great job @Fillet. I think you should also comment on why the first is closed and the second may be open but very hard to get in